# How to Find Id of a label present inside a gridview

Tags: c#

I have a label present inside grid view i want to find the control inside a button click without using

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in MyGridView.Rows)
{          
    System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label lblName = row.FindControl("lblName") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label;
    lblName.Text = "Name";
}
```

Is there any alternative way to find the control

Comment: So you don't want to iterate through all the rows. Is your button also exists inside the GridView, in the same row with Label?

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you don't want to loop all rows but that you want to find the label in the same row where the button was clicked. Then use the button's `NamingContainer` which is the `GridViewRow`:

```
protected void button_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button) sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow) btn.NamingContainer;
    Label lblName = (Label) row.FindControl("lblName");
    lblName.Text = "Name";
}
```